# Android Programming (Adding timestamp from Database to ListView)

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

I am trying to make a Note Taking/Diary Entry Application in Android. I want that the database while updating an entry should take system time and then add it to the List View.

**list_personal.xml**
    <

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="9"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="1."
                android:id="@+id/index_personal"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Title"
                android:id="@+id/title_personal"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Description"
            android:id="@+id/description_personal"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**DatabaseHandler_personal.class**

```
 package dbms.vit.myapplication;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DatabaseHandler_personal extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public DatabaseHandler_personal(Context context) {
    super(context, DatabaseValues_personal.DATABASE_NAME, null, DatabaseValues_personal.DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { db.execSQL(DatabaseValues_personal.TABLE_NOTES_PERSONAL_CREATE);}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(DatabaseValues_personal.TABLE_NOTES_PERSONAL_DROP);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addNote(Note note){
    SQLiteDatabase db_personal = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues noteValues = new ContentValues();
    noteValues.put(DatabaseValues_personal.NOTES_TITLE_PERSONAL, note.getTitle());
    noteValues.put(DatabaseValues_personal.NOTES_DESCRIPTION_PERSONAL, note.getDescription());

    db_personal.insert(DatabaseValues_personal.TABLE_NOTES_PERSONAL, null, noteValues);
    db_personal.close();
}

public void updateNote(Note note){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues noteValues = new ContentValues();
    noteValues.put(DatabaseValues_personal.NOTES_TITLE_PERSONAL, note.getTitle());
    noteValues.put(DatabaseValues_personal.NOTES_DESCRIPTION_PERSONAL, note.getDescription());

    db.update(DatabaseValues_personal.TABLE_NOTES_PERSONAL, noteValues, DatabaseValues_personal.NOTES_ID_PERSONAL + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(note.getId())});
    db.close();
}

public void deleteNote(String id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String deletequery= "DELETE FROM " + DatabaseValues_personal.TABLE_NOTES_PERSONAL + " WHERE " + DatabaseValues_personal.NOTES_ID_PERSONAL + " = '" + id + "'";

    db.execSQL(deletequery);
    db.close();
}

public List<Note> getAllNotes(){
    List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery= "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseValues_personal.TABLE_NOTES_PERSONAL;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{

            Note note = new Note();
            note.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            note.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            note.setDescription(cursor.getString(2));

            notes.add(note);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return notes;


}
}
```

**DatabaseValues_personal.class**

```
 package dbms.vit.myapplication;



    public class DatabaseValues_personal {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 13;

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "personal_note";

    public static final String TABLE_NOTES_PERSONAL = "personal_notes";

    public static final String NOTES_ID_PERSONAL = "id";
    public static final String NOTES_TITLE_PERSONAL = "title_personal";
    public static final String NOTES_DESCRIPTION_PERSONAL = "description_personal";
    public static final String NOTES_DATE_PERSONAL = "data_personal";

    public static final String TABLE_NOTES_PERSONAL_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NOTES_PERSONAL + "( " + NOTES_ID_PERSONAL + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + NOTES_TITLE_PERSONAL + " TEXT, " + NOTES_DESCRIPTION_PERSONAL + " TEXT, " + NOTES_DATE_PERSONAL + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT (strftime('%s','now')) ";

    public static final String TABLE_NOTES_PERSONAL_DROP = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NOTES_PERSONAL;

    }
```

Comment: Please show the effort you have so far invested into solving this problem and any research you have conducted. Also, only post the parts of your code which help us to answer your problem.

Comment: @Vashisht, what is your confusion? or problem?

Comment: @Wizard I am trying to make a note taking application. I want that the note while adding automatically takes the system time on creation and displays it in the list view